# Recursive -flattenMap: with Reactive Cocoa + OctoKit (fetching dynamic object graph from web service)

Tags: objective-c, recursion, github, functional-programming, reactive-cocoa

I'm trying to pre-fetch an object graph of files in a Github repository using [Octokit](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.objc) which depends on [Reactive Cococa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa). I'm running into an issue creating a signal that will drill down, recursively, until there are no more directories to be fetched. Here is an example directory graph of a [repository of mine](https://github.com/rnystrom/RNGridMenu) (note: files have been omitted to keep the graph simple and clean).

[image: Directory graph of RNGridMenu]

```c
- (RACSignal *)fetchContentTreeForRepository:(OCTRepository *)repository {
    return [[self fetchContent:Nil forRepository:repository parentContent:nil] doCompleted:^{
        // fetching tree finished, persist in database
    }];
}

- (RACSignal *)fetchContent:(OCTContent *)content forRepository:(OCTRepository *)repository parentContent:(OCTContent *)parentContent {
    return [[[[self.client fetchContents:content forRepository:repository] collect] deliverOn:RACScheduler.mainThreadScheduler]
            flattenMap:^RACSignal *(NSArray *fetchedContents) {
                // set the contents that were fetched
                id<OCTContentStoreProtocol>store = content ?: repository;
                store.contents = fetchedContents;

                // only search for contents of type "dir" (directory)
                NSArray *directories = [fetchedContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contentType = \"dir\""]];
                NSMutableArray *signals;
                for (OCTContent *fetchedDir in directories) {
                    [signals addObject:[self fetchContent:fetchedDir forRepository:repository parentContent:content]];
                }
                return [RACSignal merge:signals];
            }];
}
```

As a note: `-fetchContents:forRepository:` builds a request path and returns a `RACSignal` that enqueues an HTTP request operation (it tries to follow the semantics [OctoKit does](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.objc/blob/master/OctoKit/OCTClient.m#L436-L438)).

The problem I'm running into currently is that this setup only executes the fetch for the contents of the repository (i.e. the top-level object in the graph). `-flattenMap:` is called, the array of signals is appropriately created, and the `-merge:` is returned. The intention is to create a recursive chain that ends when there are no more directory type children (should probably add a `-filter:` to check for that).

The intension is to fetch the entire graph of files for a Github repository and be notified when the operation is finished. Here's an example of how I'd like to handle calling this:

```c
[[[GHDataStore sharedStore] fetchContentTreeForRepository:self.repository]
 subscribeNext:^(NSArray *contents) {
     // this would be called each time a new set of contents is received
     NSLog(@"received %i contents",[contents count]);
 }
 error:^(NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"error fetching: %@",error.localizedDescription);
 }
 completed:^{
     // this would be called when mapping the graph is finished
     NSLog(@"finished fetching contents");
 }];
```

Any idea why it only executes the top level? I would have thought that calling `-subscribeNext:` on `-fetchContentTreeForRepository:` would be what executes the returned signal for `-flattenMap:`, but it seems I'm misunderstanding something. This assumption comes from the [chaining example](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa#chaining-dependent-operations) in the Reactive Cocoa readme.

edit: [I am dumb.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410144/940936)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you never initialize your `NSMutableArray` of signals:

```
NSMutableArray *signals;
for (OCTContent *fetchedDir in directories) {
       [signals addObject:[self fetchContent:fetchedDir forRepository:repository parentContent:content]];
}
return [RACSignal merge:signals];
```

Change that first line to `NSMutableArray *signals = [NSMutableArray new]` and it seems to work.

Comment: I might also add that you could just use the `rac_sequence` property of the `directories` array to perform a map of each directory to the signal. Does the same thing but is bit more declarative.